# Compile but crash, initializing subclasses

Tags: c++, initialization

My program crashes when I try to pass this line:

```
Character::Character(sf::Vector2f &position, sf::RenderWindow* _pWin, World* _pWorld) 
: MobileObject(_pWin, _pWorld), moving(false)  **<-----**
{ 
    world_pos = position; 
    UpdateParent();
    txCharacter.loadFromFile("images/asdf.png"); //tmp
};
```

MobileObject is as follows:

```
class MobileObject : public Object {
public: 

    virtual void Draw()=0; 
    virtual void Update()=0; 

    MobileObject(sf::RenderWindow* _pWin, World* _pWorld) 
    : Object(_pWin), pWorld(_pWorld) { 

        world_pos.x=0;
        world_pos.y=0;
        UpdateParent();

    };
```

And Object as follows:

```
class Object {
public:
    Object(sf::RenderWindow* _pWin) : pWin(_pWin) { };

    virtual void Draw()=0; 
    virtual void Update()=0;

    sf::Vector2f world_pos;
    float z;

    sf::RenderWindow* pWin;
};
```

Crash is:
`Unhandled exception at ... in ...: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.`

Why does this happen?

Comment: Have you tried using break points? A debugger?

Comment: Yes, the program crashes exactly in the line I marked, giving only that error. The exception seems to be somewhere in <list>

Comment: What does `UpdateParent` do? And where does `pWorld` come from?

Comment: Considering that it's an access violation, I would double check what you're reading. Are you reading a private class member? Are one of your pointers null?